# Docker - An error occurred

Tags: docker

Não consigo executar o Docker que instalei no Windows 10. Tanto a BIOs quanto o Hyper-V estão habilitados, mas mesmo assim não executa.

> Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled

Comment: Possui log do erro? Adicione se possível.

Comment: Ele tenta inicializar e aparece a caixa de mensagem. Não sei onde acho o log de erro do Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o Hyper-V está desabilitado ou o Hypervisor agent não está sendo executado. Abra o PowerShell como administrador e utilize:
1. Para habilitar o Hyper-V:
 
   dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All 
2. Para habilitar o Hypervisor:
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto 
Após isso reinicie o Windows. Se o problema persistir seu Hyper-V está corrompido, então vá até o Painel de Controle -> Programas -> Recursos do Windows e desmarque todos os componentes pertencentes ao Hyper-V.
O Hyper-V tem como requisito *virtualização de hardware*, verifique se seu computador possui, caso positivo e continue não funcionando possivelmente sua BIOS está mal configurada, neste caso configura a BIOS e habilite este recurso.

Comment: Deu certo!
Obrigado

Comment: Apenas complementado a resposta. O processado deve suporte ao Second Level Address Translation (SLAT). Utilize o comando `systeminfo` para verificar isso. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v. Caso nao tenha esse suporte não vai funcionar.